# Is the fact that voltage drop is equivalent for each branch of a parallel circuit derived from Ohm's law or physical observation?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, resistance, parallel, ohms-law

e.g.

[image]

In the above image voltage drop is equivalent across each parallel branch even though each branch has different resistance values. Was this fact derived from manipulation of Ohm's law or through circuit observation using electronic tools (e.g. voltmeter)?

Comment: Any components placed in parallel will always have the same voltage across them...

Comment: I think I've completely over complicated it

Answer (score 3):

> Ohm's Law or physical observation

Neither. It's a definition.

At least, it's a definition within the circuit theory that the schematic you've drawn implies.

The schematic shows a battery, two nodes, and two resistors. A node (in circuit theory) is a single point. We draw it as something that looks like a wire, simply to make a tidy drawing. However, a node will have the same voltage at all of its connections. The node labelled '12 V' has 12 V at all the components it connects to. Similarly the '0 V' node has the same voltage at all the connections. By definition, all components strung between a pair of nodes will have the same voltage between those nodes.

What happens if the wires in the real world have resistance? Then you draw them as resistors, not wires, if the voltage drops matter. Or approximate them as wires/nodes if the voltage drops are irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

If your battery has zero impedance and can supply sufficient current the voltage across those resistors is 12V.

However, all these "laws" are idealized abstractions and never precisely match physical reality.

Answer (score 0):

> *Was this fact derived from manipulation of Ohm's law or through
> circuit observation using electronic tools (e.g. voltmeter)?*

- You have an ideal 12 volt battery. That generates an ideal 12 volts across its terminals.
- You have ideal wires connecting the battery terminals to your resistors.
- That ensures that there is always 12 volts across your resistors.

All of this has nothing to do with ohm's law or observations with any measurement equipment.

Comment: Yeah I think I completely overcomplicated it